# gradlew task console output is not readable

Tags: android, gradlew

I am trying to run some android junit unit test on the terminal (Windows 10 gitbash) but when I run the `test` I get a non readable output

```
 ./gradlew test
```

[image]

Does anybody knows why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a know issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13279

A current workaround is to add an alias in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh`

```
alias gradlew='TERM=cygwin ./gradlew'
```

[image]